# What do the Block Device Capability flags mean?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, block-device

Linux block devices in sysfs have a `capability` file, partly documented [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/block/capability.html). Well, one is documented.

Looking in `genhd.h` as it suggests, there are others. Is there any documentation on them, or does anyone know what they mean?

Listed here for convenience:

- GENHD_FL_REMOVABLE
- GENHD_FL_CD
- GENHD_FL_UP
- GENHD_FL_SUPPRESS_PARTITION_INFO
- GENHD_FL_EXT_DEVT
- GENHD_FL_NATIVE_CAPACITY
- GENHD_FL_BLOCK_EVENTS_ON_EXCL_WRITE
- GENHD_FL_NO_PART_SCAN
- GENHD_FL_HIDDEN

More specifically,

Removable? Like removable USB drives? Relation to /sys/block/*/removable? Redundant?

Whats extended devt?

suppress partitions?

no part scan? Different from suppressing partitions?

UP?

CD? Like "this is a CD drive"? Why? Means something else?

Native capacity?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any documentation, you'll have to read the source code. For `*_CD` is clear that it's "cd-like", for `*_UP` it means alive (just like with a network interface), `*_SUPPRESS_PARTITION_INFO` means they won't appear in `/proc/partitions`, etc.

Comment: `*_FL_REMOVABLE` is defined in a comment from `drivers/mmc/core/block.c`: "As discussed on lkml, `GENHD_FL_REMOVABLE` should:
         __-__ be set for removable media with permanent block devices
         __-__ be unset for removable block devices with permanent media".

Comment: I'm asking here because I myself don't have the time nor skill to inspect and understand how they all might be used throughout Linux or what they mean.

Comment: Do you happen to know what "CD-like" means for block devices? What makes them so different from others they need a special flag?

Comment: Do you happen to know how/where _SUPPRESS_PARTITION_INFO is set? Is this something userspace can control?

Comment: About _SUPPRESS_PARTITION_INFO: I don't think so. IIRC only the [null block device](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/block/null_blk.html) and the loop device driver sets it. Download the source code and `grep -r` is your friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with kernel 6.3, [the `capability` file is deprecated and always indicates 0](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=e81cd5a983bb35dabd38ee472cf3fea1c63e0f23).

At the time the question was asked, the only documented flag wasn’t used any more! The others had the following meaning:

- `GENHD_FL_REMOVABLE`: the block device provides access to removable
  media. The block device doesn’t appear or disappear depending on the
  availability of media. This is appropriate for example for CD-ROM drives (the block device is always present), but not for devices which behave like USB storage (where the block device is only present as long as the drive is connected).
- `GENHD_FL_CD`: the block device is a CD-ROM-style device. Affects
  responses to the `CDROM_GET_CAPABILITY` `ioctl`.
- `GENHD_FL_UP`: indicates that the block device is “up”, with a
  similar meaning to network interfaces. This is mostly used for synchronisation with other block device subsystems, to avoid races on removal.
- `GENHD_FL_SUPPRESS_PARTITION_INFO`: don’t include partition
  information in `/proc/partitions` or in the output of
  `printk_all_partitions()` (as shown in the kernel logs). Used for
  the null block device and some MMC devices.
- `GENHD_FL_EXT_DEVT`: the driver supports extended dynamic `dev_t`,
  i.e. it wants extended device numbers (`BLOCK_EXT_MAJOR`, [block major 259](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/devices.html)). This
  affects the maximum number of partitions.
- `GENHD_FL_NATIVE_CAPACITY`: based on information in the partition
  table, the device’s capacity has been extended to its native
  capacity; *i.e.* the device has hidden capacity used by one of the
  partitions (this is a flag used so that native capacity is only ever
  unlocked once). This could happen for example if a drive is partitioned, then has a [host-protected area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_protected_area) created which covers part of a partition.
- `GENHD_FL_BLOCK_EVENTS_ON_EXCL_WRITE`: event polling is blocked
  whenever a writer holds an exclusive lock.
- `GENHD_FL_NO_PART_SCAN`: partition scanning is disabled. Used for
  loop devices in their default settings and some MMC devices.
- `GENHD_FL_HIDDEN`: the block device is hidden; it doesn’t produce
  events, doesn’t appear in sysfs, and doesn’t have an associated
  `bdev`. Implies `GENHD_FL_SUPPRESS_PARTITION_INFO` and
  `GENHD_FL_NO_PART_SCAN`. Used for multipath devices.

Most of these have since been removed, or moved to more appropriate locations; [only `GENHD_FL_REMOVABLE`, `GENHD_FL_HIDDEN` and `GENHD_FL_NO_PART` remain](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/blkdev.h?id=e81cd5a983bb35dabd38ee472cf3fea1c63e0f23) (`GENHD_FL_NO_PART_SCAN` was renamed to `GENHD_FL_NO_PART` and indicates that the device does not support partitions).

Comment: I can see `_REMOVABLE` being useful, but then how do you detect whether theres actually anything in it or not? Do you just have to try and fail to read the device file? I hope not, since that would require root.

Comment: Yes, you’d try opening it, and handle the resulting `ENOMEDIUM`. If you don’t have the privileges required to read the device, it makes no difference whether there’s media or not, because you wouldn’t be able to act on it ;-). If the system can act on it on your behalf (*e.g.* mounting a device through your desktop environment), the part that does so is supposed to act sensibly.

Comment: Thats.. disappointing. What about the `size` file in sysfs? Would that report `0` in this case maybe? I'd check myself but don't have a CD drive. It's useful to know even without privileges to get some basic info on connected devices, like size and existence.

Comment: Apparently not, my CD drive’s `size` entry is non-zero even though there’s no CD in the drive.

Comment: What size does it report? Maybe It's a sentinel or some integers max value?

Comment: 925468, which doesn’t look like a sentinel, or even a sensible size for a CD! (The last CD in the drive was an audio CD, that might have something to do with it.)

Comment: What if it's just returning/leaking garbage data or something :o that'd probably not be good? Its getting that value from somewhere and it isnt a CD