# How can I tell if a Linux block device is trimmable or not?

Tags: linux, block-device, trim

`fstrim` requires the Linux block device to be mounted, and it is not very verbose. `blkdiscard` could tell, but also that would require a write operation.

Can I somehow tell if a block device supports trimming/discarding, without actually trying to trim/discard something on it?

Comment: /sys/block/*/capabilities has no bit for that ([ref](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/block/capability.html)).

Comment: Heh, those docs came straight from [this answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/571106/86440) ;-).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can check the device’s maximum discard sizes, *e.g.*

```
$ cat /sys/block/X/queue/discard_max_hw_bytes
```

(replacing `X` as appropriate).

If this shows a value greater than 0, [the device supports discards](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/stable/sysfs-block):

> A
> `discard_max_hw_bytes` value of 0 means that the device does not
> support discard functionality.

The maximum *supported* discard size is indicated by `discard_max_bytes` in the same directory; this can be smaller than the hardware-supported value to limit discard latencies (and can be written to to change the limit):

> While `discard_max_hw_bytes` is the hardware limit for the
> device, this setting is the software limit. Some devices exhibit
> large latencies when large discards are issued, setting this
> value lower will make Linux issue smaller discards and
> potentially help reduce latencies induced by large discard
> operations.

This works on many different block devices, not just disks: loop devices, device mapper devices, etc.

Answer (score 9):

Utilize the `hdparm` command, which lets you perform low level commands on a disk device.

The option `hdparm -I /dev/sda` (or insert block device instead of sda), will query the drive for information. There is a section that lists the supported operations of the drive.

Running `hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep TRIM` on a TRIM supporting drive will output something like:

```
    *    Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 1 block)
```

There is also a lot of other useful information in the output, the hdparm command is very useful.

Note this will only work on SATA and some SCSI devices, since `hdparm` is designed to run SATA commands on devices.

Comment: So why does `fstrim` only trim **mounted** "devices"?

Comment: @Jeremy because `fstrim` trims file systems, not block devices — it asks the file system to trim itself, so the file system has to be mounted. If you want to discard blocks from a block device, without mounting it, use `blkdiscard`; you’ll have to figure out which blocks to discard.

Comment: Note that `hdparm` only really works for ATA devices (and possibly some SCSI devices). NVMe, MMC/SD, some USB devices, device-mapper targets, ramdisks, and plenty of other device types _do not_ return any useful information when you run `hdparm -I` against them.

Answer (score 4):

To check if the device supports trim/discard one can also use linux `lsblk` utility.
If the device's discard limits like `granularity` and `max_sectors` is non-zero, then the discard/trim support is enabled, e.g.,

```
$ lsblk -D
NAME      DISC-ALN DISC-GRAN DISC-MAX DISC-ZERO
sda              0      512B       2G         0
```